# Why do my LSTM network shows a global train accuracy lower than 100% even if minibatch accuracy is 100% for all the batches in the last 20-30 epochs?

Tags: matlab, lstm

I have a problem with a LSTM network for a sequence-to-one classification problem (MATLAB 2020a and 2019b).
Here is the problem. I have a dataset which I divided 60% for training and 40% for test (cross-validation actually). The data are organized in a cell array of sequences, and the outputs in categorical arrays for both training set and test set. The sequences of the training set are sorted from the shorter to the longer, and a miniBatchSize of 32 is selected. The zero padding is then done for each batch according to the longest sequence of the batch. That is, no shuffle is performed between each epoch.
When I train the network with the SGDM method I get 100% accuracy for all the minibatches of the last epochs, so I have a completely flat training accuracy curve stucked at the 100% value. When I stop the training, the global accuracy "cls_train" (see row 26) value is not 1, but around 0.7. I completely understand that if some batches shows 100%, but others shows a lower accuracy, the global accuracy cannot be 100%, but here is different: for the last 20-30 epochs I always get 100% of accuracy  for all the minibatches, but suddendly the global train accuracy does not reach 100%.
The test accuracy is around 70%, too, but I think this is a different problem (probable overfitting), right?
Thank you everyone!

````
```
% Network architecture
layers = [sequenceInputLayer(inputSize)]; 

% add NUM_layers LSTM layers
for i = 1:NUM_layers
    layers = [layers,lstmLayer(numHiddenUnits,'OutputMode','last')];
end

layers = [layers,...
            fullyConnectedLayer(numClasses),...
            softmaxLayer,...
            classificationLayer];

options = trainingOptions('sgdm',...
    'Momentum',beta,...
    'ExecutionEnvironment','cpu',...
    'InitialLearnRate',mu,...
    'MaxEpochs',MaxEpochs,...
    'MiniBatchSize',miniBatchSize,...
    'Plots','training-progress',...
    'SequenceLength','longest');

display('Training');
NET = trainNetwork(train_data,train_class,layers,options);
cls_train = classify(NET,train_data,'MiniBatchSize',miniBatchSize,'SequenceLength','longest');

%% PERFORMANCE
accuracy_train = sum(cls_train == train_class)./numel(train_class);

cls_test = classify(NET,test_data,'MiniBatchSize',miniBatchSize,'SequenceLength','longest');
accuracy_test = sum(cls_test == test_class)./numel(test_class);
````

```
[Screenshot of the code][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UozFD.png
```

Comment: Please paste the code into your question instead of posting a screenshot of it.

Comment: You're right @Null. I did it, thanks for the suggestion. Let me know if the last part of the code is sufficient to give me some hints or if you need a higher overview.